# A simple java program

Tags: java

I have a problem statement

Problem

Write a program to calculate the sum of 2 numbers and print the output.

Input

Line 1: An integer.

Line 2: An integer.

Output :The output consists of a single integer which corresponds to sum, followed by a new line

Sample Input I

```
3 
1
```

Sample Output I

```
4
```

Sample Input II

```
13 
10
```

Sample Output II

```
23
```

To which my solution is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Add {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    int a=0, b=0, sum;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers to be summed");
    try{
        a=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        b=sc.nextInt();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Please enter an Integer number");
        e.printStackTrace();}
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

    sum=a+b;

    System.out.println(sum);
    sc.close();
}

}
```

I'm supposed to submit it to an online directory, that I assume tries to execute the program automatically. And when I do, it tells me

Wrong Answer    Almost there,think some more

I think pondering over it for an hour is more than enough before you decide to call in for reinforcement.

Comment: +1 if you were honestly pondering about the problem for the past 1 hr.

Comment: You should change your title.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think SO is a place to get your homework done. Hate me or whatever, but read the rules before you post.

Comment: There is no rule against asking for help with homework. The code posted appears to be complete and only has one specific problem with the output format.

Answer (score 10):

The output should be "a single integer which corresponds to sum, followed by a new line".

But the output of your program is

```
Enter the numbers to be summed
<the sum>
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `sc.nextLine()`. It makes it move to the next line, but since both integers are on the same line, the value for b remains at 0.

Comment: The 2 integers are not on the same line. The question says: Line 1: An integer. Line 2: An integer.

Comment: still get rid of that line and try again. Using next int, a nextLine isnt neccessary even if they are on separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

These can be solve by two thing command line  arguments or Scanner class or BufferReader.

**Using the Command line Arguments.**

```
public Class Sum
   {

     public static void main(String [] args) 
     {
          int a ,b,c;
          a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);   //using Integer wrapper Class to cast object  
                                           to primitive Datatype Integer.

          b= Integer.parseInt(args[1])  ;

          c= a+b;


         System.out.println("The Sum of two number is : "+c);
     }

   }
```

**Using Command Line Arguments with code re usability(Method Sum)**

```
public Class Sum
   {

     public static long sum(int a,int b)
     {
          return a+b;
     }

     public static void main(String [] args) 
     {
          int a ,b;
          long c;           // for long summation of numbers .

          a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);   //using Integer wrapper Class to cast object 
                                           to primitive Datatype Integer.

          b= Integer.parseInt(args[1])  ;

          c= sum(a,b);


         System.out.println("The Sum of two number is : "+c);
     }

   }
```

**Using  the External resources from the java.util.Scanner**

```
    public Class Sum
   {

     public static void main(String [] args) 
     {
          int a ,b;
          long c;

          Scanner scan;

          scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;  //Taking system Keyboard for input.

          System.out.println("Enter the value of A: \n");

          a= ss.nextInt() ;

          System.out.println("Enter the value of B: \n");

          b=ss.nextInt();

          c= (long) (a+b); 

         System.out.println("The Sum of two number is : "+c);
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
        num1 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Number2: ");
        num2 = in.nextInt();

        sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package stack;
public class Satck {
    public static int MAX=100;
     int top;
    int [] a= new int [MAX];
  boolean  empty()
    {
        return (top<0);
    }
 Satck()
    {
        top=-1;
    }
 void push(int x)
 {
         a[++top]=x;
     
 }
 public int pop()
 {
    
     int x=a[top--];
         return x;
    
 }
 public int peek()
 {
         int x=a[top];
         return x;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     Satck s=new Satck();
     s.push(10);
     s.push(11);
     s.push(12);
     s.push(13);
     System.out.println(s.peek());
     System.out.println(s.empty());
     System.out.println(s.pop());
     System.out.println(s.peek());
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).